# Any way to set keepalive in DBI connect method in Perl

Tags: perl, dbi, amazon-redshift

I am using DBI and DBD::Pg to connect to Postgres Database (actually RedShift in AWS). One problem I have is that I can't find a way to specify keepalive option. I can find some instruction on JDBS though. Essentially I would like to achieve to keep the connection between my client and RedShift until either side explicitly disconnects (right now it is disconnected by firewall since there is no activity when some operation takes a while).

Answer (score 2):

`DBI` leaves this up to the individual DBD modules, many of which do not address this issue. For `DBD::Pg` in particular, I see that you can pass an `options` parameter to [`connect`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBD::Pg#connect), but I can't find any documented option that seems relevant.

`DBI` does give each database handle a [`ping`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#ping) method, which returns 0 if the connection is valid, or non-0 otherwise. You could use that to check if a connection is still valid, then re-connect if needed.